# combining 2 tables in MySQL select statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I know I can do joins but its not exactly what I want.

I'm making a live chat system that has 2 tables mainly:  the main chat table (call it table a), and then a mod table (call this one table b).  If a user gets suspended, messages reach over 100 for that channel, or they are over 1 week, the messages get moved from the main chat table to the mod table.

I store the ID of the chat messages as ID(primary) on the main chat table and as chatID on the mod table.

What I'm doing is making a separate page for my Mods and I want to be able to combine the two tables into 1 area but I want them to be ordered by their respective tables.

So lets say we had the following:

Main table ID's: 1,2,4
Mod table ID: 3

I want my results to show up 1,2,3,4 no matter which table the ID is in.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I got the answer and this is what I used to do so:

```
SELECT ab.* FROM 
  ((SELECT ID as table_id FROM a 
    WHERE roomID = 'newUsers' ORDER BY ID ASC) 
UNION ALL 
  (SELECT chatID as table_id FROM b 
    WHERE roomID = 'newUsers' ORDER BY chatID ASC)) ab 
ORDER BY ab.table_id
```

Comment: @jeffran, thanks for the feedback, *(don't forget to format your code so it doesn't all run on a single line :-)*

Comment: Is this faster/better or just for formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `UNION` in a subselect.

```
SELECT ab.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as table_id, * FROM a
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as table_id, * FROM b
) ab
ORDER BY ab.id
```

If you want the result of table A to appear **before** table B, change the query to:

```
SELECT ab.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as table_id, * FROM a
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as table_id, * FROM b
) ab
ORDER BY ab.table_id, ab.id
```

**Some background**
`UNION ALL` will merge two <strike>tables</strike> resultsets into one resultset.
`UNION` will do the same but will eliminate duplicate rows.
This takes time and slows things down, so if you know there will be no duplicate records *(or you don't care about dups)* use `UNION ALL`.

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Comment: What is ab?  Is that just a temp name, or both of them put together?

Comment: @jeffran24, You need to give the inner select a name, so MySQL knows what you're talking about. It's not a temp table, it just a name for the union of the two.

Comment: and when you do 1 as table_id would 1 be like ID and 2 be like chatID (given in my example above)?  This way I can sort them at the end?

Comment: @Jeffran, yes I made up id's to be able to tell which table the rows come from.

Comment: I got it to work and will include my final SQL statement that did it.  Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: Ok one more question :) - Is there a way I can tell where the data came from?  Like if it came from table 2?

Comment: SELECT ab.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as table_id, * FROM a
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as table_id, * FROM b
) ab WHERE table_id = 2
ORDER BY ab.table_id, ab.id